# How to merge two json objects to get one json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I am trying to merge/combine two json objects to get one final json object(merged object). I have tried the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kuunpmx9/4/), but I am getting like: `[object Object]` if I use $.extend and `Uncaught TypeError: testjson1.concat is not a function` error if I use cancat. Please help me how can I get my required json object either using javascript or jquery or angularJS ?

Comment: Don't alert. Try logging it in console and it should work. Or do `JSON.stringify(finalObject)` to convert the object in string.

Comment: first one _is_ want you want

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kuunpmx9/2/

Comment: JSON,stringify(obj, null, 2) prints the object even prettier

Comment: The example final result JSON is actually the same as `testjson1`. Can you update the fiddle?

Comment: It's already giving me the correct answer. Use `console.log` for printing instead of `alert`. Also, prefer this `$.extend({}, testjson1, testjson2)` over `$.extend(testjson1, testjson2)`.

Comment: @Qwerty, I have updated my fiddle in the question.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla, I have updated my fiddle in the question as my testjson1 was having some wrong json previously

Comment: BTW, you are not really using JSONs. Those are already JavaScript objects. JSON is text only `'{"key":value}'` and can be converted into JavaScript object with `JSON.parse('...')`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to convert the JSONs into javascript objects, then perform the merging like so and convert back to JSON.

> [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Basically iterate over the keys and assign them.

```
var obj1 = JSON.parse(testjson1),
    obj2 = JSON.parse(testjson2)

for (var attrname in obj2) { obj1[attrname] = obj2[attrname] }

var finaljsonresult = JSON.stringify(obj1)
```

But this is just a sneak peak, you might want to see the linked answer for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is tagged with **AngularJS**, why not convert the JSONs to JavaScript objects using [angular.fromJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson) and then merge them with [angular.merge](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge)?

Unlike [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend), angular.merge recursively descends into object properties of source objects, **performing a deep copy**.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj1 = {
        'a': 'aa',
        'b': 'bb',
        'c': 'cc'
    },
    obj2 = {
        'a': 'aa',
        'd': 'dd',
        'e': 'ee'
    };

for (var key in obj2) {
    obj1[key] = obj2[key]
}

var res = JSON.stringify(obj1);
alert(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery for that.

Answer (score -2):

```
The Extend keyword in jquery making stringify:
  var object1 = { 
                 apple: 0, 
                banana: { weight: 52, price: 100 }, 
                cherry: 97 
                };
        var object2 = {
                         banana: { price: 200 },
                         durian: 100};
        var ss = $.extend(object1, object2);
        alert(JSON.stringify(ss));
```

Comment: Use appropriate formatting for code while posting comments or answers.